# calling the classes and functions python

Tags: python, function, class

i'm fairly new to python programming. i have two text files, one of them is my main program and the other one is the file containing a set of functions and classes which is used in the main file. my question is how can i use the functions and classes in the function file and how to call them to run the main file properly, and where i should place this function file in the directory ? 
this is a sample for my function file :

```
from numpy import *
####################################################################
#################################################################### 
class C1:

####################################################################
####################################################################
def F1:

####################################################################
####################################################################
def F2:

####################################################################
#################################################################### 
class C2:
.
.
.
```

Comment: maybe this will help you a bit http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply import the function file into your main.py. Let us say it is called funcs.py. Then you can just say:

```
# near the top of the file
from funcs import F1, F2, C1
.
.
result = F1(p, q, r) + F2(p, q, r)
c1 = C1()
```

Answer (score 0):

Place both files in the same dir, and then in your main file do:

```
import [name of function file]
```

From then on you can do

```
foo = [name of function file].C2([your args here])
```